# HTML JS запретить ввод текста в INPUT

Tags: javascript, html

Есть `input type text` в который при определенных условиях нужно запретить ввод текста.

Я знаю о существовании атрибута `disabled` но хотел бы узнать есть ли прямая альтернатива по аналогии к примеру с ссылкой: `a href="/" onclick="return false;"` то есть мы не добавляем ссылке никаких атрибутов или свойств, просто при клике "пропускаем переход".

Возможно ли сделать такое же в `input`? Чтобы он так же оставался `enabled` с мигающим индикатором, но при вводе текста чтобы просто ничего не происходило и значение не вписывалось.

Comment: Чем атрибут readonly не угодил?

Comment: @andreymal мне не угодил disabled, а readonly про который я забыл то что надо, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Правильным решением будет использовать атрибут `readonly`, а не `disabled` и не скрипты:

```html
<input value="2121" readonly>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно повесить обработчик событий, который будет "удалять" нативный функционал

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');
input.oninput = e => {
  e.target.value = ''; // не важно, что ввели, значение всегда пустое будет
}
```

```html
<input id='input' >
```

Answer (score 0):

Данный код выполняет вашу задачу, но только при вводе с клавиатуры.

```js
function SupressInput($event)
{
  $event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<input type=text onKeyPress=SupressInput(event);>
```

Comment: у вас ошибки в коде

Comment: @ThisMan исправила,теперь работает))

Comment: Не то событие - я могу мышкой вставлять) К тому же, подписка не так и так себе.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpPvg.gif